# How to identify the MAC address of built-in wifi in python

Tags: raspbian, python, networking, wifi

I'm experiencing some difficulties when I attempt to identify the MAC address of the built-in wifi in my raspberry pi 3 model B. My application requires the built-in wifi to always be identified as wlan0 (not to mix interface name with other wifi adapter connected)

I have had success configuring the wifi adapter manually, when I know the mac address of the adapter. Such as using the the 70-persistent-net.rules to set the interface name such as:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="b8:27:cc:cc:cc:cc", NAME="wlan0"
```

However, this manual method is undesirable and I’m seeking an automated method that would allow configuring a new raspberry using an image, rather than configuring it with SSH or other ways.

Does anyone know a method to in python to read and identify the correct mac address of built-in wifi and write a new 70-persistent-net.rules to name this wifi to interface to wlan0?

I thank you all in advance!

Comment: possibly helpful in SO, for old questions check for newer answers: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159137/3904031), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24196932/3904031), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/159137/3904031)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is by installing [netifaces](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/netifaces) (prepend `sudo` if it doesn't work), Just do:

```
pip install netifaces
```

After that is done, check the current interface's name in the terminal by typing

```
ifconfig
```

and remember it or write it down. After that, paste the following in a new python script and replace `'your_interface_name'` with the name you got before (in string form) and save the script with the name of your choice:

```
import netifaces

IFNAME = 'your_interface_name'

MAC = str(netifaces.ifaddresses(IFNAME)[netifaces.AF_LINK][0]['addr'])
print MAC #Check if MAC parsing is ok

file = open('/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules','a+')
file.write('''ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="%s", NAME="wlan0"\n''' % MAC)
file.close()

file = open('/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules','r')
print file.read() #Check if new rules were written successfully
file.close()
```

That's it. I don't have a Raspi with me, and I don't remember if `70-persistent-net.rules` is write protected, but just run the script with `sudo` if it doesn't work.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a program that gets the MAC addr for every interface

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fcntl, socket, struct
from os import walk

def getHwAddr(ifname):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    info = fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8927,  struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15]))
    return ''.join(['%02x:' % ord(char) for char in info[18:24]])[:-1]

def getIPAddr(ifname):
    if (ifname == "lo"):
        return "127.0.0.1"
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    try:
        info = fcntl.ioctl(s.fileno(), 0x8915, struct.pack('256s', ifname[:15]))
    except:
        return "No address assigned"
    return socket.inet_ntoa(info[20:24])

f = []
path = '/sys/class/net'

for (dirpath, dirnames, filename) in walk(path):
    f.extend(dirnames)
    break

for iface in f:
    print "Interface:", iface
    print "IPv4 Addr:", getIPAddr(iface)
    print "HW MAC Addr:", getHwAddr(iface)
    print "-----------------------------"
```